# Should I use KeyPressEvent or QAction to implement keypresses?

Tags: qt, keyboard, keyboard-events

In Qt, either implementing keyPressEvent or creating a QAction and assigning it a key combination allow me to act based on the keyboard.

Which of these methods is generally preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use QAction whenever the same event that is triggered by the key sequence you want may be triggered through other ways like from a menu, toolbar or other buttons. This way you can use the same action on several widgets that should do the same trick.

Excerpt from [QAction doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaction.html):

> The QAction class provides an abstract
> user interface action that can be
> inserted into widgets.
>
> In applications many common commands
> can be invoked via menus, toolbar buttons, and
> keyboard shortcuts. Since the user
> expects each command to be performed
> in the same way, regardless of the
> user interface used, it is useful to
> represent each command as an action.

Comment: Also, QAction makes it easier to override the key combination you want to use at run-time. It's certainly possible to achieve this using the other method as well, but harder.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to overwrite the `keyPressEvent`. I don't like the idea of a `QAction` "lying around somewhere". Just overwrite the `keyPressedEvent`. I usually do it with a switch-case in which I check the pressed key. Just don't forget to call the keyPressEvent of the base class if you don't want to disable the standard behaviour of a key. Additionally you can check if a "modifier" is pressed while a `keyPressEvent` occurs. (e.g. Shift or Ctrl). IMHO for general purposes overwriting the `keyPressEvent` is better than creating invisible, secret actions, unless you want your application to contain all those actions visible for the user.

```
void my_widget::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* p_event )
{
    bool ctrl_pressed = false;

    if( p_event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier )
    {
        ctrl_pressed = true;
    }

    switch( p_event->key() )
    {
    case Qt::Key_F:
        focus_view();
        break;

    case Qt::Key_I:
        if( ctrl_pressed )
        {
            toggle_interface();
        }
        else
        {
            QWidget::keyPressEvent( p_event );
        }
        break;

    case Qt::Key_Return:    // return key
    case Qt::Key_Enter:     // numpad enter key
        update_something();
        break;

    default:
        QSpinBox::keyPressEvent( p_event );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would depend on what you need it for.

Is it for a menu like action that may be triggered by a menu, button, toolbar too, then go for the QAction. Especially if this action should work all over your program, not only in a single widget.

Is it more like a local activity in a single widget (say for example controlling movement in a game), I would use the keypress event.